# Simplest way to support logging from a VSTO AddIn

Tags: c#, logging, vsto

I have written a simple MS Word AddIn in Visual Studio 2013, and I would like to be able to log events, preferbly to the Windows Event Viewer. It seems that I will run into permission issues if I try to create a new event source for my application. I am looking for the simplest approach to enable logging events from my VSTO that does not violate good programming guidelines.

#### Option 1: Use the VSTO 4.0 source

I see from the MSDN documentation on [Event Logging for Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442816.aspx) that:

> You can use the event viewer in Windows to see exception messages that
>   are captured by the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime when you
>   install or uninstall Office solutions. You can use these messages from
>   the event logger to resolve installation and deployment problems.

These events are logged using the `VSTO 4.0` source. Can I use the `VSTO 4.0` source to log errors from my own AddIn, or would this considered bad practice?

**Edit:** From Eugene Astafiev's answer and what I've read elsewhere it seems this would be a bad approach since the `VSTO 4.0` source is only supposed to deal with the management of the AddIns, not the AddIns themselves. [Answers to other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024260/in-windows-what-default-event-sources-are-available-in-the-application-event-lo) have also advised against using "generic" sources.

#### Option 2: Create a bootstrap app to be included in the installer

As an alternative, I could include a simple bootstrap application which creates the source during installation, but I can't see how to add my own prerequisites using the Install Settings under Properties > Publish in Visual Studio. Can it be done? Is there another way to do it? I would prefer not to have to create an [InstallShield Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) since in every other respect the installer created by default works well for my purposes. It seems like overkill to create a full installer just to get event logging working.

**Edit:** So far, it seems that there is no "easy" way to do this, although it is not too complicated to create an installer by following the linked instructions.

#### Option 3: Use a logging framework and log to a file

A third option would be to use log4net or similar logging framework and configure a File Appender to log to a file.

Initially I was not very keen to implement file logging, because a) My application would not be logging very frequently, and b) I wanted to avoid having log files scattered in various locations that are hard to find.

**Edit:** This is the option I have taken so far, since it required the least configuration and is adaptable if my logging requirements change in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is relatively straightforward to setup **log4net** to handle simple (or complex) logging requirements. The [log4net Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial) on CodeProject provides a useful reference.

1. Install log4net to your project using the NuGet Package Manager or Package Manager Console if you prefer.
2. Add an `App.config` file if you don't have one already (right-click your project, select **Add > New Item...** and select **Application Configuration File** from Visual C# Items).
3. Edit the `App.config` file to look something like this (replacing MyAddIn appropriately in the `<file />` tag):

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <configuration>
     <configSections>
       <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" requirePermission="false" />
     </configSections>
     <log4net>
       <root>
         <level value="ALL"/> 
         <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
       </root>
       <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
         <file value="${APPDATA}\My AddIn\MyAddin-log.txt" />
         <appendToFile value="true" />
         <rollingStyle value="Size" />
         <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
         <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
         <staticLogFileName value="true" />
         <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
           <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
         </layout>
       </appender>
     </log4net>
   </configuration>
   ```

   Log files will be saved to the user's roaming **AppData** (`%appdata%`) folder, keeping up to 5 rolling log files which do not exceed 5MB each.
4. Add the following line to `ThisAddIn_Startup()` in ThisAddIn.cs (you will need to add a `using log4net;` directive):

   ```
   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
   ```
5. Add the following statement to any class which needs to implement logging:

   ```
   private static readonly log4net.ILog log = 
       log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
   ```
6. Events can then be logged using the `log.Info`, `log.Warn`, `log.Error`, `log.Fatal` and other methods provided by log4net.

You may get schema warning messages because log4net does not include a schema, and Visual Studio cannot then validate the config section. In that case, download the schema file from http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd to somewhere accessible. The location `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas` [has been suggested](http://answersunlimited.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-fix-warning-messages-like-could.html) elsewhere.

Select your `App.config` file in Visual Studio, and click into the editor. You should get an **XML** menu item. From there, select **Schemas...** and add the log4net.xsd file from where you saved it.

Note that you can also use log4net to [log to the Event Viewer](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#eventlogappender) but you will run into the same permission issues raised in the initial question.

Comment: I think one important step is missing which is mentioned here: https://stackify.com/log4net-guide-dotnet-logging/ you need to add an entry to the AssemplyInfo.cs to let you Plugin know where to find the config file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to differentiate VSTO exceptions that can be captured when installing or uninstalling the software and add-in specific events handled in your code. The [Event Logging for Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442816.aspx) article explains how to capture the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime exceptions when you install or uninstall Office solutions.

If you need to log the add-in events you can use any .Net based components and BCL. For example, see [What is the best way to write event log entries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313839/what-is-the-best-way-to-write-event-log-entries).

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I ended up using log4net. Could you clarify what you mean by "use any .Net based components and BCL"?

Comment: BCL stands for Base Class Libraries, they proide classes for working with the windows event log. .Net components - log4net.